# Windows based couchbase image for docker

Tags: docker, couchbase

Is windows based image for "couchbase" available to install with docker? or any way around so that couchbase can be installed with docker in windows container.

Comment: Isn't this working? https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/couchbase/

Comment: $ docker run -d --name db -p 8091-8093:8091-8093 -p 11210:11210 couchbase   
.Unable to find image 'couchbase:latest' locally                           
latest: Pulling from library/couchbase                                    
docker: image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform.   
See 'docker run --help'.

Answer (score 0):

The images are based always on Linux. You know an image is based on other image recursively till reach a base image like ubuntu, debian or whatever. Anyway, it is suppossed they are not related to the host O.S. They can be run on a Docker using a Windows host, Linux host or OSX host in the same way. On Windows or OSX you can install Docker to run container based on Linux images, there is no problem about that.

Depending of the use of the container, if it needs some hardware to be useful (like wireless cards or something like that), then the host is important because there are drivers and kernel directly involved. But usually, any image can be used to run containers independently of the Docker host.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (2017-10-02), I don't think there is an official Couchbase Docker image for Windows container.  Their [Dockerfile](https://github.com/couchbase/docker/blob/master/enterprise/couchbase-server/4.6.3/Dockerfile) shows that their images are built off of Ubuntu.

You can try setting everything up manually by following the steps below.  (Note that installing via Chocolatey is just a convenience.  You can choose another method.)

1. Get [Windows Server Core](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/windowsservercore/) image.

   ```
   host> docker pull microsoft/windowsservercore
   ```
2. Start the container in interactive mode

   ```
   host> docker run -it --name couchbase-on-windows microsoft/windowsservercore
   ```
3. Switch to PowerShell

   ```
   container-cmd> PowerShell
   ```
4. Install [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install#installing-chocolatey)

   ```
   container-ps> Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
   ```
5. Install [Couchbase](https://chocolatey.org/packages/couchbase-server-community).  (The version on chocolatey might be a bit behind the latest.)

   ```
   container-ps> choco install couchbase-server-community
   ```

If all this works to your liking, then you can create a Dockerfile to make your own Docker image.  You can see what this person did to create an image for [Redis on Windows](https://blog.alexellis.io/packaging-windows-containers/).  Here's his [Dockerfile](https://github.com/alexellis/aspnet-voteservice/blob/master/images/redis/Dockerfile).